# I am getting Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in Magento2

Tags: magento2, installation, fatal-error

I am getting the error `Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found` in Magento2 after installation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just need to clear comment before this line in `php.ini` file:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

**to**

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Comment: In my `/etc/opt/remi/php70/php.ini' not has `;extension=php_intl.dll`.
I install php7 in `/opt/remi/php70`. Any suggestion?

Comment: recompiled again with an additional parameter (--enable-intl)

Answer (score 5):

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl` did the trick for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

(That's with this PPA repo containing a backport of PHP `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`.)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but in my case `intl` was installed and loaded checking `php -m`. `brew install icu4c` resolved issue on my Mac. I'm using php 5.6.30 by the way.