# Error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in AbstractFactory.php Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I checked all the similar issues related to this topic and almost everyone says to install php intl module.
However I have it installed and loaded.
Did anyone have similar issue?
Magento 2.4
php7.4
Debian 10
Fresh installation
All the cache flush reindexing, seutp:upgrade done as well

regards
Piotr

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86661/i-am-getting-fatal-error-class-intldateformatter-not-found-in-magento2

Comment: @CoderKubeTechnologies please read my question once again.